# How to dynamically set Solr shards on Spring Data Solr query

Tags: java, spring, solr, spring-data, spring-data-solr

How can I pass shard information on a spring-data-solr query? Using the SolrJ interface I can set:

```
SolrQuery query = new SolrQuery();
query.add("shards", StringUtils.join(shardList, ","));
...
```

I would like to do the same with spring-data-solr but don't directly see how this can be done. Do I have to create a new Query and QueryParser that implement the requested behavior and then some how register these classes as a new QueryParserPair?

Is there another concept in spring-data-solr I'm not "yet" familiar with that allows me to do the same in a different way?

Any help/pointer is welcome.

Thanks and greetings,

Vincent